# Save search query with enabling filtering (advanced filters)

Tags: feature-request, search, filtering

Is there an option to filter questions using the followin search query?

```
[feature-request] closed:no score:10
```

If I do this now there are no questions found.

I've it about this feature:

[image]

I've added my result when I type the query:

[image]

So you can see `closed:no` and `score:10` are added as tags. It doesn't recognize as only open and +10 questions or answers.

I've added a sketch of what I'll to have:

[image]

With the *save* button there will be a filter saved like on the first image.

Comment: Aaaaah, then it's clear now - there's no result because [closedno] isn't an existing tag

Comment: And neither is score10; you're trying to add filters as tags. It doesn't work like that.

Comment: @Jenayah: yes it's that I mean

Comment: So your question is about enabled _filters_ to be added through the _tag_ field?

Comment: @fbueckert: I know. 'cause of that I've opened a feature request

Comment: Well, that's something I'm going to disagree with.  There's a perfectly good search bar that does that.

Comment: @fbueckert: and I'll save that search so I don't need to redo it every time

Comment: @Jenayah: yes, I'll add this my question

Comment: @fbueckert: I've updated my question

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: it's not about the Andoid app. I only use the responsive website.

Comment: (What do mean by *"I've it about this feature"*? Perhaps a word is missing?)

Answer (score 5):

This is about enabling filters to be added through a tag field. Pedantic considerations aside, this... doesn't seem especially urgent to work on.

The search bar is already available and the `closed:`, `answers:` etc operators work completely fine. One can simply write in the search bar, it... doesn't take *that* long.

I get that one would want to save such searches - for now, I think bookmarking should work just fine.

A better feature, I think, would be to add a completely new submenu, under, say, "Advanced search", allowing to include operators and their value. Something like my crappy HTML sketch below...

> [image: multiple advanced filters]

Comment: Your sketch looks good, but can you save the operators and there values? I ask this 'cause this is my question... Just add a save button.

Comment: @H.Pauwelyn by "save", you mean like bookmark the thing? Sure, that could be added, actually there's even a "Save filter" button already. The skecth above would be located between, say, "Tagged with" and the line separator above the buttons.